# Append and remove Div dynamically based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I am able to add div dynamically based on dropdown value. But after change to another value in dropdown previous div add to new div. how i remove previous one. Please see my code below.

```
$(function () {
        $("#HowmanyClone_Id").change(function () {
            debugger;
            var cloneCount = $(this).find(":selected").text();                
            $(this).closest("div.row").remove();
            for (var i = 1; i <= cloneCount; i++) {
                $("#Div_Quick_Clone").append('<div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;"> Serial Number:<input type="text" name="" class="form-control "> <div>  </div> </div>');
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
   <div id="Div_Quick_Clone" style="display: none;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            No of Clones :</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%=Html.DropDownList("HowmanyClone_Id", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                            new SelectListItem{ Text="Select To Clone", 
                    Value = "Select" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="2", Value = "2" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="3", Value = "3" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="4", Value = "4" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="5", Value = "5" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="6", Value = "6" },
                        }, new { id = "HowmanyClone_Id" })%>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Just add 
$("#Div_Quick_Clone").html('')
below ''debugger' in your JS

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#HowmanyClone_Id").change(function() {
  var cloneCount = $(this).find(":selected").text();
  $("#Div_Quick_Clone").find("div.row").remove();
  for (var i = 1; i <= cloneCount; i++) {
    $("#Div_Quick_Clone").append('<div class="row" style="margin-top:10px;"> Serial Number:<input type="text" name="" class="form-control "> <div>  </div> </div>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Div_Quick_Clone">
  <div class="editor-label">No of Clones :</div>
  <select id="HowmanyClone_Id">
    <option value="Select">Select To Clone</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

You need to change $(this).closest("div.row").remove() with $("#Div_Quick_Clone").find("div.row").remove() only.

Comment: @Harry everything is perfect just replace what I mentioned above. No need to change more.

Comment: **$(this).closest("div.row").remove()**  it will not find any tag in case of you want to delete so you need to catch parent tag and then find appropriate object.